# How to write a function for the day AFTER Thanksgiving? Holiday gem, YAML files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, yaml

I'm writing an app that tracks time-off via date ranges, and part of my calculations make sure to exclude weekends and holidays. In order to keep track of holidays I'm using a forked version of the Holidays gem(https://github.com/alexdunae/holidays), editing it to recognize holidays that my company recognizes. My fork: (https://github.com/rclark4/holidays).

So far everything has worked just fine for me, but I've run into a problem with the day after Thanksgiving, which is an addition to the original gem. This is an excerpt of what the YAML file looks like:

```
  11: 
  - name: Thanksgiving
    week: 4
    regions: [us]
    wday: 4
  - name: Day after Thanksgiving
    week: 4
    regions: [us]
    wday: 5
```

While this works from 2008-2012, this doesn't work in 2013 (and won't every 6-7 years), because this November starts on a Friday, so right now it's saying that the day after Thanksgiving is a week before it actually is. I've tried to look at the syntax of all the other holidays to see if there was a precedent for holidays that happened the day AFTER a floating holiday, but I couldn't find one (the closest thing I found was Good Friday to Easter, but Easter has it's own separate method altogether). Any ideas on how to write a function for this?

Let me know if you need any more information!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shawn's answer is mostly correct but you are actually supposed to put region specific methods in the original file. The idea is, you shouldn't need to touch the .rb files to make new definition, just the .yaml files. lib/holidays.rb is really for general code rules (like to_weekday_if_weekend, etc.), not for rules specific to a region. I know it's kind of confusing that it works even if you don't follow the rules exactly, an upcoming release (hopefully) this summer will change that soon.

So in us.yaml for November it should be:

```
11: 
- name: Thanksgiving
  week: 4
  regions: [us]
  wday: 4
- name: Day after Thanksgiving
  function: day_after_thanksgiving(year)
  regions: [us]
```

and under methods in the same file (where us_inauguration_day is defined, at least in the master version) should be:

```
methods:
us_inauguration_day: |
# January 20, every fourth year, following Presidential election
   def self.us_inauguration_day(year)
     year % 4 == 1 ? 20 : nil
   end
day_after_thanksgiving: |
  def self.day_after_thanksgiving(year)
    Date.civil(year,11,Date.calculate_mday(year,11,:fourth,:thursday)+1)
  end
```

Then run rake defs:build_all (run rake defs:manifest when you add a new region file)
And I pulled your copy to match against your test, but as a reference:

```
tests: |
  {  Date.civil(2008,11,27) => 'Thanksgiving',
     Date.civil(2008,11,28) => 'Day after Thanksgiving'}.each do |date, name|
       assert_equal name, (Holidays.on(date, :us)[0] || {})[:name]
     end
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanksgiving is the 4th Thursday in November, so the day after is that day +1.   Date.calculate_mday is added by holidays gem.

in lib/holidays.rb

```
def self.day_after_thanksgiving(year)
  Date.civil(year,11,Date.calculate_mday(year,11,:fourth,:thursday)+1)
end
```

in data/us.yaml   change the holiday to:

```
 - name: Day after Thanksgiving
    function: day_after_thanksgiving(year)
    regions: [us]
```

make sure you have jeweler installed

```
 rake defs:build_all
```

Then run the tests:    [test_full_week was broken already]

```
 rake
```

Then rebuild your gem.

Note:
It might make more sense to define thanksgiving as the method, and then use the function for its definition in the yaml file and thanksgiving+1 for the friday after.